# how to subscribe to a specific topic in node js using MQTT asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, hivemq

I configured HiveMQ server and installed the MQTT npm package in the node js. I published the message to the HiveMQ server from different system in the same network.I want to subscribe the message asynchronously. How to achieve this?
Code Snippet :

Published from different system to the HiveMQ

```
    client.on('connect', function(){
        client.publish('Test', 'test Message');
    });
```

Want to subscribe from HiveMq asynchronously

```
    client.on('connect', function(){
        client.subscribe('Test');
    });  

    client.on('message', function(topic, message){
    });
```

Comment: That looks right - you haven't shown your `.connect` call, but I assume you got that right

Comment: thanks for the respone Jaromanda, am able to receive the message properly from MQTT broker[HiveMq], but it is in blocking state[Synchronous].. but i want this to behave asynchronously. 
var client = mqtt.Client(HiveMq server ip address);

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise HiveMq wasn't an MQTT broker

Comment: any approach where i can use "subscribe" asynchronously.

Comment: you are, in the connect callback